# How to manage Daily Bonus push notification with One Signal?

Tags: unity-game-engine, push-notification, onesignal

We have a daily bonus system working on date basis. Every date in your local time, you have right to take 1 daily bonus. Ex: If you get daily bonus on 12 July, you will get right to take next bonus on date 13 July without depending on time.

I would like to create push notification for users, but i could not sort it out how to do it?

My previous tries:

1- Whenever player gets daily bonus, i tried to create notification for the next day at 8 pm in her local time.

Problem: If player takes bonus on the next day before 8 pm, i could not delete previously created notification, because there is no delete function for Unity. I also tried collapse_id to deal with it, but collapse_id do not stop sending the notification, just updates notification info with the last one when it is received.

2- I created a tag which is the date when bonus collected, it is something like "2018-07-12". I tried creating a user group who compares these tag with the "today's date"

Problem: there is no such thing like todays date you had to enter it as value, so you can do this by entering console changing date and sending notification and you need to do it everyday.

How can I create such notification system?

Thanks.
Hasan

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options to do this with OneSignal.

1 - You can cancel the notification if the user already took the bonus.

You can use something like this to make the cancel request:

```
string url = ""https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications/"" + notificationId.ToString() + ""?app_id="" + s_appId;

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
request.Method = ""DELETE"";
request.GetResponse();
```

2 - If you are tracking this on your own CRM or database, then you can save the OneSignal PlayerID to the database and target device with the API.

First, get the playerID with the SDK: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/unity-sdk#section--getpermissionsubscriptionstate-

Then you can send this data to your CRM or database: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/internal-database-crm
​
You can then use `include_player_ids` on the create notification REST API POST call https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-send-to-specific-devices

If you want to go the tagging option, you should use a timestamp and then target with the API and filters https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-send-to-users-based-on-filters

You should never put your OneSignal REST API key within your app. This needs to be kept private.